# How to read OpenOffice version in Java (1.6)

Tags: java, plugins, version, openoffice-writer, openoffice-api

I'm a C# developer and actually i have to develop some functions in Java 1.6 for an OpenOffice-PlugIn.
One of these functions is to get some meta informations of environment like the version of the executing OpenOffice. 
On Google i didn't find something. I know that a registry entry exists. But that is just a subkey without a value.
Does anybody know, how i can get the Version Number of the executing OpenOffice with Java 1.6?

Edit:

Now i have the solution. I will help other developer, if they have the same issue. It must be only capsuled in a method.

```
XComponentContext componentContext = com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap.bootstrap();
        XMultiComponentFactory xRemoteServiceManager = componentContext.getServiceManager();


        Object configProvider = xRemoteServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext( "com.sun.star.configuration.ConfigurationProvider", componentContext);
        XMultiServiceFactory xConfigProvider = (XMultiServiceFactory) UnoRuntime.queryInterface( XMultiServiceFactory.class, configProvider);

        PropertyValue[] lParams = new PropertyValue[1];

        lParams[0] = new PropertyValue();
        lParams[0].Name = "nodepath";
        lParams[0].Value = "/org.openoffice.Setup/Product";

        Object xAccess = xConfigProvider.createInstanceWithArguments( "com.sun.star.configuration.ConfigurationAccess" , lParams);

        XNameAccess xNameAccess = (com.sun.star.container.XNameAccess) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XNameAccess.class, xAccess);

        String OOVersion = (String)xNameAccess.getByName("ooSetupVersion");
        return OOVersion;
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this example code](https://github.com/LibreOffice/loeclipse/blob/master/java/source/com/artofsolving/jodconverter/openoffice/connection/OpenOfficeConfiguration.java) of how to use [ConfigurationProvider](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/configuration/ConfigurationProvider.html) interface. You may find [this python example](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=19202) helpful also to understand how things work.

```
NODE_PRODUCT = "org.openoffice.Setup/Product";
public String getOpenOfficeVersion() {
        try {
            // OOo >= 2.2 returns major.minor.micro
            return getOpenOfficeProperty(NODE_PRODUCT, "ooSetupVersionAboutBox");
        } catch (OpenOfficeException noSuchElementException) {
            // OOo < 2.2 only returns major.minor
            return getOpenOfficeProperty(NODE_PRODUCT, "ooSetupVersion");
        }
}

public String getOpenOfficeProperty(String nodePath, String node) {
        if (!nodePath.startsWith("/")) {
            nodePath = "/" + nodePath;
        }
        String property = "";
        // create the provider and remember it as a XMultiServiceFactory
        try {
            final String sProviderService = "com.sun.star.configuration.ConfigurationProvider";
            Object configProvider = connection.getRemoteServiceManager().createInstanceWithContext(
                sProviderService, connection.getComponentContext());
            XMultiServiceFactory xConfigProvider = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                com.sun.star.lang.XMultiServiceFactory.class, configProvider);

            // The service name: Need only read access:
            final String sReadOnlyView = "com.sun.star.configuration.ConfigurationAccess";
            // creation arguments: nodepath
            PropertyValue aPathArgument = new PropertyValue();
            aPathArgument.Name = "nodepath";
            aPathArgument.Value = nodePath;
            Object[] aArguments = new Object[1];
            aArguments[0] = aPathArgument;

            // create the view
            XInterface xElement = (XInterface) xConfigProvider.createInstanceWithArguments(sReadOnlyView, aArguments);
            XNameAccess xChildAccess = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XNameAccess.class, xElement);

            // get the value
            property = (String) xChildAccess.getByName(node);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw new OpenOfficeException("Could not retrieve property", exception);
        }
        return property;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am however looking for a method of querying the Version of the running OO Version from within my Addin and was hoping not to having to use a library, but rather that OO offers the possibility for its addins to query the version. Does anyone know if this is possible?